# Resize non sequential column reference to the first row

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone tell me how I can resize a column reference to the first row in a worksheet?

I get errors (for different reasons on both) which is understandable but still frustrating:

Attempt 1:

```
Dim Columns_To_Export as String
    Columns_To_Export ="$B:$C,$E:$E"

Range(Columns_To_Export).Resize(1).Select
```

Attempt 2:

```
Dim Columns_To_Export as String
    Columns_To_Export ="$B:$C,$E:$E"

Colulumns(Columns_To_Export).Resize(1).Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I wasn't very attentive with my above response. Here is what I believe is a better try.

```
Private Sub SelectCells()
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print CellsForExport("$B:$C, $E:$E, G").Address
End Sub

Function CellsForExport(ByVal Desc As String) As Range
    ' 15 Apr 2017

    Dim Fun As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim Spi() As String, Spj() As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim Cstart As Long, Cend As Long

    Desc = Replace(Desc, "$", "")
    Spi = Split(Desc, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Spi)
        Spj = Split(Trim(Spi(i)), ":")
        Cstart = Columns(Trim(Spj(0))).Column
        Cend = Cstart
        If UBound(Spj) Then Cend = Columns(Trim(Spj(1))).Column
        With ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(Cstart), .Cells(Cend))
        End With
        If Fun Is Nothing Then
            Set Fun = Rng
        Else
            Set Fun = Application.Union(Fun, Rng)
        End If
    Next i

    Set CellsForExport = Fun
End Function
```

The function `CellsForExport` returns a range as specified by the calling procedure `SelectCells`. The calling procedure in this case doesn't select the range. Instead it prints its address. That is for testing purposes. `CellsForExport("$B:$C, $E:$E, G").Select` will select the cells. You could also paste this range somewhere or manipulate it in any other way you can manipulate a range.

Note that you can omit the `$` signs when specifying the columns. You also don't have to specify `E:E` to define a single column, but if someone does all that the macro will sort it out. Blank spaces don't matter, commas are of the essence.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response.  Thank you so much for your help.  I've tested through this and it seems to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `Column` is a range, not a string. This code will do the job.

```
Dim Rng As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = Application.Union(.Columns("B"), .Columns("C"), .Columns("E"))
End With
Rng.Select
```

Comment: I should probably mention, I'm going to be referring to a cell on the worksheet that has those Column references entered in it.  I'm not going to have the luxury of parsing them out like you showed above.  Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: I just realized too, your solution still doesn't solve the issue of resizing the column range to just the first row.  I get the same error message as with my first attempt.  Try replacing your last piece of code `Rng.Select` with `Rng.Resize(1).Select` and you'll see what I mean